# Scott Wlaschin ThinkOfNumber example

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find my way in functional programming with haskell.
I saw this nice video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDe-4o8Uwl8 by Scott Wlaschin.
I'm tryng to implement his ThinkOfNumber example using haskell.

[image: Think of a number, F#]

The only solution I found is this one:

```
thinkOfANumber  numberYouThoughtOf =  (\x -> x - numberYouThoughtOf) 
                                      . (\x -> x / numberYouThoughtOf) 
                                      . (\x -> x - 1) 
                                      . (\x -> x * x) 
                                      . (\x -> x + 1)
```

So I have to invoke the function in this way, using 2 parameters

```
thinkOfANumber 13 13
```

in order to memorize the numberYouThoughtOf in the call chain.

I there a way to simplify the code, using a pipe like operator such as the "|>" operator in F# ?

Maybe I'm surely missing something :)
Regards.
Ivan

edited after the nice Fyodor Soikin response:

In case someone is interested in the Scott Wlaschin presentation, here is a possible haskell solution to the toRomanNumerals example:

```
import Data.List.Utils

  infixl 5 |>
  x |> f = f x

  toRomanNumerals number = 
      let replicate_I     = ['I' | _ <- [1 .. number]]
          replace_IIIII_V = replace "IIIII" "V"
          replace_VV_X    = replace "VV" "X"
          replace_XXXXX_L = replace "XXXXX" "L"
          replace_LL_C    = replace "LL" "C"
          replace_CCCCC_D = replace "CCCCC" "D"
          replace_DD_M    = replace "DD" "M"
      in replicate_I
         |> replace_IIIII_V
         |> replace_VV_X
         |> replace_XXXXX_L
         |> replace_LL_C
         |> replace_CCCCC_D 
         |> replace_DD_M
```

Thanks again fyodor soikin!

Comment: I mean, you could just write the whole thing in one line `think n x = (a * a - 1) / n - n where a = x + 1`

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The F# pipe operator is available as [`(>>>)`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.19/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Arrow.html#v:-62--62--62-) in the `Control.Arrow` module. You could also try using [operator sections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator).

Comment: @bradrn the `>>>` operator from `Control.Arrow` is actually composition, whereas F# pipe is reverse application.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Fyodor Soikin - I'm not too familiar with F#. In that case `(&)` would indeed be the correct choice as you said below.

Answer (score 2):

[Operator `&`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.19/base-4.11.1.0/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) from `Data.Function` is the exact analog of the F# pipe:

```
thinkOfANumber numberYonThoughOf = 
    let addOne x = x + 1
        squareIt x = x * x
        subtractOne x = x - 1
        divideByTheNumberYouThoughtOf x = x / numberYonThoughOf
    in  numberYonThoughOf 
        & addOne
        & squareIt
        & subtractOne
        & divideByTheNumberYouThoughtOf
```

Of course, if you like the pipe (I personally do), you can always define it in Haskell:

```
infixl 5 |>
x |> f = f x

thinkOfANumber numberYonThoughOf = 
    let addOne x = x + 1
        squareIt x = x * x
        subtractOne x = x - 1
        divideByTheNumberYouThoughtOf x = x / numberYonThoughOf
    in  numberYonThoughOf 
        |> addOne
        |> squareIt
        |> subtractOne
        |> divideByTheNumberYouThoughtOf
```

Comment: Thank you. Really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Fyodor Soikin is correct that `&` corresponds to F#'s `|>`, but my impression from reading Haskell code is that it's considered more idiomatic to use the `$` operator and compose from right to left, like in mathematics:

```
thinkOfANumber numberYouThoughOf = 
  let addOne x = x + 1
      squareIt x = x * x
      subtractOne x = x - 1
      divideByTheNumberYouThoughtOf x = x / numberYouThoughOf
  in divideByTheNumberYouThoughtOf $ subtractOne $ squareIt $ addOne numberYouThoughOf
```